# Find the area enclosed by the line $x=5$ and the parametric curve $x=6t-t^2, y=e^{3t}$

Tags: calculus, area, parametric

Well, I have written the question above. This is what I tried, even though all of this is quite messed up, and I’m sorry for that. Could anybody guide me through the complete solution? Can you just solve it down here? I’ll understand if I see the solution. [image: First][image: Second[![Third]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDgLc.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDgLc.jpg)

Comment: To solve the explicit curve put in $t$ from parameterization of $x$ to get $y=\exp(9\pm3\sqrt{9-x})$.

Comment: How did you get this?

Comment: The parameterization of $x$ in terms of $t$ is a quadratic equation in $t$. $x=6t-t^2\rightarrow t=3\pm\sqrt{9-x}$. $y=\exp(9\pm3\sqrt{9-x})$.

Comment: And what do I need to do next? What will this change?

Comment: Your explanation is very hard for me to get, since I am very new to this, can you solve the problem and write it here, or tell me what was wrong in the solution that I wrote on the very left and got a 1.99?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The curve intersects with the vertical boundary $x=5$ at $x=6t-t^2=5$, which yields $t=1$ and $t=5$. Note that the area is to the right of the boundary $x=5$, which is shaded in the graph.

Thus, the area integral is given by

$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2} (x-5)dy=\int_1^5 (6t-t^2-5)(3e^{3t})dt
=\frac29 e^3(7+5e^{12})$$

Comment: I don't quite get why it is to the right of x=5, and even if it is why did you subtract 5 from x, isn't 6t-t^2 the bottom function? Shouldn't you subtract it from 5 like this: (5-6t-t^2)? And also, why can't I just write integral from 1 to 5 (6t-t^2)(3e^(3t))dt??? why should I include that 5? I still don't quite get the whole to the right of 5 thing. I think since the two functions are present before x=5 we should integrate it up to x=5, where it will be the very bottom function.

Comment: @ArmanBabayan - I added a graph to indicate the integral area, which is to the right of the bound $x=5$. Thus,  $6t -t^2 - 5 \ge 0 $ is used in the integrand.

Comment: in your graph, don't you need to subtract x from 5, not the other way around since the top function is x=5?

Comment: Also, why do you only find the area of that small part to the right of x, where you can just do integral from y1=1 to y2=5 (6t-t^2)(3e^(3t))dt ??? won't this cover everything?

Comment: @ArmanBabayan - Note that, for $t\in[1,5]$, the top of the function is $x=6t-t^2$, which is greater than $x=5$.

Comment: @ArmanBabayan - the problem asks to integrate the area enclosed by the curve and the boundary $x=5$. So, you only integrate the part that is to the right of $x=5$. If you ignore $x=5$, you get the area enclosed by the curve and the $y$-axis.

Comment: I am confused cause in the graph, which I graphed on desmos I see otherwise. up until the x=5 the dominating function is 6t-t^2 which is bigger than x=5, after the x=5 vertical line it kinda goes smaller than x (the end part of the parabola), so if you really want to calculate the part on the right (which I don't understand why, shouldn't you subtract 6t-t^2 from 5?)

Comment: @ArmanBabayan - you may not have the right graph. Make sure you graph using $t$ as the parameter, not x.

Comment: So just to be clear I have two questions, and sorry for taking so much of your time. 
1) Considering only the part to the right of x=5 feels a little bit wrong, since when you graph it in desmos, the y=e^3x part is not even there at all, it's just one line x=5 and a small part of the parabola of the function 6t-t^2.
2) Is the bigger function in this case the parabola 6t-t^2 cause in that part from x=5 to the right (up until the vertex of the parabola), it has a bigger x-axis position than x=5?

Comment: @ArmanBabayan - 1) due to the large scaling along the y direction, e.g. $y_2=e^{15}$, , most plotters would not do that. They stop at certain point, which is why you don't even see it. 2) is correct.

Comment: Okay one final question, when the problem asks for area enclosed with a line x=something, we always consider the functions that are to the right of it?

Comment: @ArmanBabayan - not always. it depends on the curve. For instance, in your previous post, the area is to the left of $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, but when graphing the other problem, I got that x=0 was the bigger function since it was to the right of the parabola, and that is why you put an absolute value bar (0 - the parabola function), but wasn't y=e^2t the biggest function there cause it was right-er than the rest? Ah no, I got it thanks.

Comment: small note, applying the limits $t = 5$ should make an $e^{15}$ term (and not $e^{12}$)

Comment: @Quanto you literally saved me, thank you so much, for continuing to explain it to me after all these questions!

Answer (score 0):

We have to find the area bounded by $x=5$ and
$$y=\exp(9-3\sqrt{9-x})$$
**How we reached here**: 
$$x=6t-t^2$$
$$ t^2-6t+x=0$$
This is a quadratic in $t$. Applying the formula and solving for $t$ , we'll get:
$$ t= \dfrac{6\pm\sqrt{36-4x}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow t=3\pm\sqrt{9-x}$$
Plugging this $t$ in the parametric equation of $y$, we get: 
$$y=\exp(9 \pm 3\sqrt{9-x})$$
We consider only 
$$y=\exp(9-3\sqrt{9-x})$$
The other equation we get by solving for the explicit curve is ignored because of this graph :
[image]
Assuming we want the area bounded from $-\infty$ to the point where the curve cuts the line $x=5$ , we have to perform the following integral :
$$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{5}\exp({9-3\sqrt{9-x}}) \  \mathrm{ d}x$$

Solving this (pretty calculative) integral ends us up with :
$$\dfrac{2\left(3\sqrt{9-x}+1\right)\mathrm{e}^{9-3\sqrt{9-x}}}{9}$$
And upon placing limits, The area bound turns out to be:
$$\dfrac{14\mathrm{e}^3}{9}$$

Comment: How do you get that y = exp stuff, I am sorry this is too hard a solution. Can you please explain it to someone that is too new to the topic?

Comment: Yes of course. I shall edit the post.

Comment: @ArmanBabayan Do you understand the answer now?

Comment: Nope, look at my comment to the other user :(

Comment: @ArmanBabayan Which part did you not get? I hope its clear how we reached the explicit curve..

Comment: I must mention that $y=\exp(9+3\sqrt{9-x})$ is ignored as when plotted, it doesn't show up in the region we're tying to focus on .

Comment: On The answer above, Paras stated that the integral from - infinity to 5 of ydx is equal to the same thing evaluated from -infinity to 1, which I don’t quite get, since our 1 and 5, were the t=1 t=5 values, and our integral was evaluated from - inf to x=5 and I don’t think x and t are the same thing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106103/discussion-between-sai-kartik-and-arman-babayan).

Answer (score 0):

$A = \int y\ dx\\
y = e^{3t}\\
x = 6t -t^2\\
dx = 6 - 2t \ dt\\
\int e^{3t} (6-2t)\ dt$

limits:

$5 = 6t - t^2\\
(t-1)(t-5) = 0$

$\int_1^5 -e^{3t}(6-2t)\ dt$

$-2e^{3t} + \frac {2t e^{3t}}{3} - \frac {2e^{3t}}{9}$

$\frac {(-20+6t)e^{3t}}{9}|_1^5\\
\frac {10e^{15} + 14e^{3}}{9}$