# Find the area enclosed by the y-axis and the parametric curve $x = t^2 - 8t + 15$; $y = e^{2t}$:

Tags: calculus, area, parametric

The title says it all. I tried this, since we need to find the area enclosed by the y-axis we could say that it is the line $x=0$, so now we can do this $t^2-8t+15 = (x-3)(x-5) = $ factorized form. Afterwards I tried the formula $A = \int_3^5 ydx$, which doesn't work. So I thought that graphing it may help. From graphic I could say that the answer may be $$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{2t} (2t-8)dt.$$ 
(Thus, an improper integral), but I don't know if this is correct and it is most probably going to output a negative area. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The curve intersects the $y$-axis at $x=t^2-8t+15=0$, which yields $t=3$ and $t=5$. Thus, the area is

$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2} |x|dy=-\int_3^5 (t^2-8t+15)(2e^{2t})dt
=\frac12 e^6(3+e^4)$$

Comment: Can you please explain where the - next to the integration symbol came from?

Comment: @ArmanBabayan - note that $x=t^2 -8t+15$ is negative over $t\in [3,5]$. The ‘-‘ ensures that the integrand for the area is positive

Comment: Thank you so much, you are the only person, whose solution was clear to me. If you please could, could you look at another question I posted here about the same topic? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601479/find-the-area-enclosed-by-the-line-x-5-and-the-parametric-curve-x-6t-t2-y-e

Comment: @ArmanBabayan - no problem. I’ll take a look

Answer (score 0):

It is not $(x−3)(x−5) = 0$; it is $(t−3)(t−5) = 0,$
or, $t=3,5$.

So, upper limit for $t$ is 5 and lower limit for $t$ is 3.

So, upper limit for $y =e^{2\times5} = e^{10}$
and lower limit for $y$ is $e^{2\times3} = e^6.$

Now integrate; area, $$A=\int_{e^{10}}^{e^6}xdy$$

Or, $$A=2\int_3^5(t^2-8t+15)e^(2t)dt$$

By the way, $dy = 2te^{2t}dt$.

Comment: I think you mixed the limits of integration position in the first integral, also dy = 2e^(2t)dt.

But I don't understand one thing: Why do these limits of integration yield to the same thing? How is e^6 = 3 and e^10 = 5????